# Random Variable Y given X

Tags: marginal-distribution

I have been given a joint probability distribution function and asked to find the marginal probability distributions.
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
λ^2e^{-λy}&0\le x\le y\\
0&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$
how do i compute the marginal distribution of x if I am not given the Y.

I know that to compute the marginal distribution of x i have to integrate over y. But how i do it if it is not given to me?

Comment: The joint describes both marginals as you can compute the integral over the variable you are not interested in and thus arrive at the marginal for the remaining variable
$$
f_X(x) = \int_0^{\infty} f(x, y) dy
$$

Answer (score 0):

When we want a marginal distribution over some variable, we have to integrate over it to remove it. Thus we have the formula
$$f_X(x)=\int f_{X,Y}(x,y)\,dy$$
In this case, the marginal distribution of $X$ is
$$f_X(x)=\int_x^\infty\lambda^2e^{-\lambda y}\,dy=-\lambda[e^{-\lambda y}]_x^\infty=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$$
(We can start from $x$ because $f(x,y)$ for $x>y$ is zero.) Similarly, the marginal distribution of $Y$ is
$$f_Y(y)=\int_0^y\lambda^2e^{-\lambda y}\,dx=\lambda^2ye^{-\lambda y}$$

Answer (score 0):

First, it is always a good idea to check that the density integrates to 1:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} f_{XY}(x,y)dxdy
&=&
\int_{y=0}^{\infty}\int_{x=0}^{\infty}{\bf 1}_{\{x\leq y\}}(x,y) \lambda^2e^{-\lambda y}dxdy\\
&=&
\int_{y=0}^{\infty}\int_{x=0}^y \lambda^2e^{-\lambda y}dxdy\\
&=&
\int_{y=0}^{\infty}y\lambda^2e^{-\lambda y}dy\\
&=&
\lambda^2y\frac{e^{-\lambda y}}{-\lambda}|_{y=0}^{\infty}-\lambda^2\int_{y=0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda y}}{-\lambda}dy\\
&=&0-\lambda^2\frac{e^{-\lambda y}}{\lambda^2}|_{y=0}^{\infty}\\
&=&1
\end{eqnarray*}
Now, the marginal density $f_X(x)$ is given by 
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_X(x) 
&=&
\int_{y=0}^{\infty}{\bf 1}_{\{x\leq y\}}(x,y)\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda y}dy\\
&=&
\lambda^2\int_{y=x}^{\infty}e^{-\lambda y}dy\\
&=&
\lambda^2\frac{e^{-\lambda y}}{-\lambda}|_{y=x}^{\infty}\\
&=&
\lambda e^{-\lambda x}
\end{eqnarray*}
You can verify this integrates to $1$ over its range $[0,\infty)$. And, for fun and excitement, we compute the marginal $f_Y(y)$ for $Y$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
f_Y(y)
&=&
\int_{x=0}^{\infty}{\bf 1}_{\{x\leq y\}}(x,y)\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda y}dx\\
&=&
\int_{x=0}^y\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda y}dx\\
&=&
y\lambda^2 e^{-\lambda y}
\end{eqnarray*}
which also integrates to $1$ over $[0,\infty)$. ${\bf 1}_{\{x\leq y\}}(x,y)$ is the indicator function which is defined to be $1$ when $x\leq y$ and $0$ otherwise.